# Div is not totally replaced in show hide command of Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have this code https://jsfiddle.net/23h4jrde/2/ that allows you to replace a div content when a button is clicked. I think the previous content is not yet fully replaced because when the new content shows it pushes down to the bottom.

```
$('.ctabtn').on('click', function(){
  $(".information").hide();
  $(".ctabtn").hide();
  $('.hosted-cities').show();
});
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this behavior, maybe some comparative screenshots would help.

Comment: Why you have 
<div class="card__img card__img--vader"> </div>
This div ? at the top

Comment: The script does not replacing the content it just hiding the targeted elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are after. But if you wish to remove the elements which are being hidden, you can try something like this.

```
   <div ID="wrapper"> //add a wrapper
       <span class="information">     
          <p class="card__text"> 2020 Winter Whiskey Tasting Festival  </p>
          <p class="card__text2"> Sat, January 25, 2020 </p>
          <p class="card__text3"> 4:00 PM – 6:00 PM CST  </p>
       </span>
       <div class="card__btn ctabtn">JOIN US</div>
    </div>

    <div class="hosted-cities">
       <p class="card__text"> Choose your City </p>
       <button class="card__btn" id="" type="button">Dallas</button>
       <button class="card__btn" id="" type="button">Denver</button>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.ctabtn').on('click', function(){
    $('.hosted-cities').show();
    $('#wrapper').remove(); //removes the div
});
```

Edited [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d2haxzw4/)

Answer (score 1):

It is hided in your example. Hided - not replaced. For replacement you can use .html() method.

The described problem can be because of several reasons:

1) ".information" or ".ctabtn" element in your original code have **!important** styles, that will ignore inline styles of hide method.

2) It can be animation problem, so you can change time durations of hiding:

```
$('.ctabtn').on('click', function(){
  $(".information").hide(0);
  $(".ctabtn").hide(0);
  $('.hosted-cities').show();
});
```

3) If you want replacement behaviour, change to .html() methods.